# Faucet valve control

Tags: home-automation, solenoid-valve

I'm a mechanical engineer with very few knowledge in electrical so your help is very appreciated.

I'm doing a small project which require to automatically the fill and empty a sink.

How can I automate the filling of the sink, make it stop (so the sink don't overflow) over a long period of time.

I've experimented a little bit with solenoid valves, but they get very hot (and I fear that they melt) if powered more than a few hours.

[Here](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07F1DYFNK/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04__o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) is the valve I used. I know I should probably use a Normally Open one.

Once again, your help is very appreciated.

*EDIT:*

I will ask my question differently.
How can I have a Normally open solenoid valve closed indefinitely?

Comment: which voltage are you using to activate the valve?

Comment: How long does it take to fill the sink when the valve is open? How long till it is necessary to refill the sink? Note that it is normal to have two water level sensors (or one that exhibits a large amount of hystersis) in an application like this so that the filling mechanism is not flopping on and off near the filled level. The upper sensor is used to turn off the fill mechanism whilst the lower one is used to turn it on.

Comment: Evaluate the time open and time closed then see if N/C or N/O or a mechanically controlled valve would be energized less..

Comment: Hello, it is 12 V to activate the valve and 270 mAmp

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE? Asking for recommendations for specific products or where to buy them are off limits for this site, so I removed them from your question. Now the answer becomes trivial: you keep the valve closed indefinitely by providing power to it indefinitely.

Comment: But as mentionned, the valve get very hot and I fear that it will burn if left powered indefinitely which is why I was looking for:

a) an alternative that let me power it indefinitely
b) a different model of solenoid that will not burn.

Comment: You should check your voltage source to make sure you are providing 12V and see what the actual current draw once the solenoid is actuated is.  Whatever current is flowing in this state is just the solenoid fighting a spring IIRC.  Consider weakening or replacing the spring.  Actuate the solenoid and then see how much you can decrease the voltage and still maintain the hold, then build a circuit to actuate the solenoid, then decrease to holding voltage.  Between these things you should be able to hold it indefinitely.  You don't make clear in your question whether the sink has automatic empty.

Comment: That's a simple but excellent recommendations that I will try and update once tested. Thank you!

Comment: You should try to find the datasheet for the solenoid.  A good one should give guidance regarding the duty cycle, temperature limits, and maybe even cooling advice.  Some solenoids require high current for the initial move, but a lower current to keep them engaged.  Also consider that there are reliable mechanical solutions, like the refill mechanism in most toilet tanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different types of valves available.  You have already discovered solenoid valves - most common are Normally Closed but Normally Open and combination Normally Open & Normally Closed are also available.

There are also motorised valves available.  Again - you can fabricate your own using a large hobby servo positioner attached to a ball valve or purchase one ready-made.

Detecting water level is possible using any of several different techniques.  You can fabricate or purchase float switches or measure the weight of the water in the vessel or use conductive probes to detect the presence of water.

You will find float switches in most dishwashers and water weight sensors in clothes washing machines.

Your best bet going forward is to research some of these options, then return here and modify your question with more information.  We will help.

Comment: The best would be an 1/2" NO valve or an motorised valve but I'm having a hard time finding a place selling ones. Could you recommend me a website selling some cheap ones and shipping to Canada?

Comment: It's been a while since I purchased valves. I would check eBay, aliexpress, deal extreme, banggood.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an update. It is very hard to find a normally open valve for cheap (not frequently used in industries I guess) so I could fix the problem by decreasing as much as possible de voltage of the valve. I could activate it at 10.5 V instead of 12 and I could decrease the voltage until 6.5 V. What I will probably do is used a few capacitor to be able to reach the 10.5 V and then maintain it at 6.5.

Thank you for your help!